# Is there UB in this code?

Tags: c, directive

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define f(x,y) \x##y

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
f(,)
```

My friend asked me the question but I don't have a definite answer for it.

Comment: Defining Exit status is a behavior. or ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `directive`?

Comment: Exactly so I have a backslash before the newline why I did not get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is a valid preprocessor token ("each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above") but it cannot be converted into any valid token (it is not in the list of `punctuator`s). Backslashes do not have any particular significance in a C program outside of character and string literals, except for the use at the end of a line.

Consequently, the macro replacement will fail the requirement in §6.4.1 paragraph 2:

> Each preprocessing token that is converted to a token shall have the lexical form of a keyword, an identifier, a constant, a string literal, or a punctuator.

so the program is not well-formed. If an executable is produced, attempting to execute it would have Undefined Behaviour.

If it were not for the backslash, the program would be well-formed. Token concatenation of two empty macro arguments is well-defined; it is replaced with nothing.

Comment: but the backslash is preceding the newline. so it has significance ?

Comment: @sabrina: it precedes an `x`. Line merging happens very early in the translation phases, long before macro substitution; even before comment recognition.

Comment: Yes, Now I see.

Comment: If a program is not well-formed, it will (or, should) be rejected by the compiler, so cannot be executed nor exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: @peter: if a program is not well-formed, a diagnostic message must be produced, but the only case in which a compiler is required to fail to produce an executable is if it encounters an `#error` directive. (See §4, paragraph 4.)  (My statement in the answer was really incorrect, so I removed it.) Particularly relevant (though non-normative) is footnote 9 to  §5.1.1.3 (diagnostics): "Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. *It may also successfully translate an invalid program.*"